# Not able to start apache 2.2

Tags: php, apache-2.2

I am trying to install apache 2.2 and wanted to do some php stuff. So I have installed the apache but I am unable to start the apache service. It showed me the error "Could not reliably determine the server’s fully qualified domain name" when it was installed successfully. I am trying to install it on windows XP machine.

Also I have uncommented the

```
 ServerName localhost:80
```

in httpd.conf file even tried by just putting

```
 ServerName localhost
```

but no success. It shows me the error request operation has failed.

Anyone could help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Even though you will get the `Could not reliably determine the server’s fully qualified domain name`, the server will infact start.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
ServerName localhost:80
```

to:

```
ServerName :80
```

the warning will go away.